# Angular dynamic directive attribute not evaluating when used with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to pass in a string that comes from a list in my controller which contains the template name that should go get the template dynamically (i.e. template="{{item.template}}")

I've attempted to do some debugging on my problem using the good ole' console.log. When the templateUrl: function (...) evaluates, it seems that Angular is not evaluating the template="{{item.template}}" as the result is {{item.template}} instead of the strings in my list.

What am I missing that would cause Angular not to evaluate the strings in my list? **Thanks in advance!**

HTML Below:

```
<workflow ng-controller="ModalController as modalController">
    <workflow-step ng-class="{'inactive' : index > 0 }" ng-repeat="(index,item) in modalController.list">           
         <dynamic-questions template="{{item.template}}"></dynamic-questions>
    </workflow-step>
</workflow>
```

Here is the DynamicQuestions directive that should dynamically use the template value from the above code snippet.

```
angular.module('app').directive('DynamicQuestions',
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',            
        replace: true,          
        templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {                
            return '/app/templates/' + attr.template +'.html';
        }           
    };              
});
```

Here is the ModalController which contains a simple list of strings I intend to use to control the dynamic template

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('ModalController',
    function() {
        var self = this;

        self.list = [
            { template: "intro" },
            { template: "contactinfo" },
            { template: "mailingAddress" },
            { template: "dateOfBirth" }
            ];
    });
```

Side Note:
I've seen some examples of dynamic directives where scope is used in the directive and then the link function is used to determine the template using

```
scope: { template: '@'},template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>'
```

Perhaps this would be a better way to accomplish my goal.

Comment: `ng-include` way should work, did you try it?